# Trigonometric Expression Problem

Tags: calculus

''Express $sin(4α)$ as a function of $α $ only''?

What does it mean? how can one express a trigonometric function using only angles?

Comment: "As a function of $a$" means you're allowed to use $\sin a$, $\cos a$, $\tan a$, and so on, but not $\sin2a$ or $\sin(a+17)$ or $\sin\log a$ and so on.

Comment: Straight and to the point...thanks man!

Comment: It's still a pretty inept way of giving an exercise, since e.g., $\sin(2\alpha)$ is after all a function of $\alpha$. What is meant is: as built from $\sin(\alpha)$, $\cos(\alpha)$ by taking sums, differences, products, etc. but not using compositions. With a little effort, all this could be made precise.

Answer (score 2):

It means only $\;\alpha\;$ can appear, not $\;4\alpha\,,\,3\alpha\;$ ,etc.

Hints: trigonometric identities:

$$\begin{align*}(1)\;\;\;\sin 2x&=2\sin x\cos x\\
(2)\;\;\;\cos 2x&=\cos^2x-\sin^2x=2\cos^2x-1=1-2\sin^2x\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

$\sin 4x=2\sin2x\cos2x=2(2\sin x\cos x)(2\cos^2x-1)$

Comment: In what way is this a hint?

Answer (score 0):

It means that you have to express $sin(4\alpha)$ as a function of trigonometric functions with only $\alpha$ as argument. Use the following formulae:

$$sin(2\alpha)=2sin(\alpha)cos(\alpha)$$

$$cos(2\alpha)=cos^2(\alpha)-sin^2(\alpha)$$